# How to write to the next available empty cell in a column?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I want my program to be able to write to the next available cell in a given column. For my case I'm trying to write to the next available cell in column A.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('purchases.xlsx')
sheet = wb['PURCHASES MADE']

sheet.max_column('A') = 'spam'
wb.save('purchases.xlsx')
```

I have a feeling I'm using the max_column line wrong, could anyone correct me on how to use this properly or if I'm using a totally wrong code line?

Answer (score 1):

`max_column`  [has no input parameter.](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html)
It gives the 1-based index of the last column containing data.

So for your use you want to to:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('purchases.xlsx')
sheet = wb['PURCHASES MADE']
cell = 'A' + str(sheet.max_column)
sheet[cell]
wb.save('purchases.xlsx')
```